# Split an a comma seperated list of number like strings as text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column which contains comma seperated numbers

`A1: 004,005,0005,00005`

I want to split and more stuff with this. When I split I end up with the following. Losing the zeros because excel parses them as text

`=split(A1, "," )`

`4 | 5 | 5 | 5`
instead of

`004 | 005 | 0005 | 00005`

The number of zeros is important. I will pass on the result to get a vertical list

`=unique(transpose(arrayformula(trim(split(join(",",!A1:A),",")))))`

Answer (score 2):

Adding a single quote before a number will keep the format as is, thus, keeping the leading and trailing zeroes. Please see formula below:

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",","#'"),"#")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\d+)","~$1"),","),"~",""))`

What this formula does is first replace every group of numbers with a tilde (~) and that same group of numbers. When `SPLIT` then acts on this new configuration, splitting at the commas, every group of numbers has the tilde in front of it and so retains all digits (because it is seen as a string and not a number). Finally, the outer `REGEXREPLACE` just gets rid of the tildes.

Answer (score 1):

With just a single value in `A1` you can use a little trick I described over at "Web-Applications" in [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149315/247436) cross-website post:

```
=SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE("'"&A1,"#","#'"),"#")
```

The single quote will force GS to format the returned elements as being text. We can use this principle inside an arrayformula if you have to concatenate multiple strings. You don't need `ARRAYFORMULA()` per se, but instead of `JOIN()` you'd need `TEXTJOIN()` to use the 2nd parameter and exclude empty cells from being joined.

[image]

**Formula** in `B1`:

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE("'"&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:A),",","#'"),"#")))
```